# PyCharm - Pick Up from where you left

Tags: pycharm

Does PyCharm have a 'Pick Up from where you left' option ?(like Google Chrome). And if so, how do I enable it ? (no search on google for 'Pycharm pick up from where you left' worked)

Comment: Do you mean that after closing and reopening you want to see the files that were open from the previous session?

Comment: @Tom Yes, that's what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are working in a Project, `Settings` > `Appearance & Behavior` > [`System Settings`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/system-settings.html) > `Startup/ Shutdown` should have the checkbox you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Check `Navigation` section in [Keymap Reference](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/keymap-reference.html). Maybe `Ctrl+Alt+Left/Right` could help.